# Replace all :parameterNames with {parameterNames} in path string

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, how would I take a string and replace values in it that match the pattern :someParameter with {someParameter}.

This is to convert url patterns that are for Express routes into the patterns Swagger uses.

Express uses: `"/api/:param1/:param2"`

and

Swagger specification uses: `"/api/{param1}/{param2}"`

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this question?

Comment: I agree @axtck. I thought it was a well formed question. I did some edits, and hopefully it would be good enough. There is a "Reopen" link if you want to vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [RegExp capture-groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#types): `/(?::)([^/]*)/g`

```
/
 (?::)   # (?:x) -> Match for, but don't remember pattern `x`
 ([^/]*) # (x) -> Match for and remember pattern `x`
         # [^x] -> Match all except `x`
         # x* -> Match for `x` 0-n times (greedy)
/g       # g -> global-flag
```

Remembered groups can be [used in the replacement-string as `$n`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) where `n` is the n<sup>th</sup> group.

```js
function expressToSwagger(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?::)([^/]*)/g, '{$1}');
}

const expressStr = '/api/:param1/:param2/someText/:param3';

console.log(expressToSwagger(expressStr));
```

Comment: So `$1` points to each group?

Comment: @axtck `$1` stands for the first group of the current match, and not for the first group overall. So yes, it basically points to the first remembered group for each match & replace. Will edit to provide a link to MDN docs.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string on `/`, then map through the outcome array and check if the item starts with `:`, if it does, return the item (without `:`) between brackets, otherwise return the item. Then `join` the array back together with a `/`.

```js
const expressString = "/api/:param1/:param2/notAParam/:anotherParam";

const result = expressString.split("/").map((part) => {
  return part.startsWith(":") ? `{${part.substring(1)}}` : part;
}).join("/");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: My first method didn't work correctly with for example `"/api/:param1/:param2/notAParam/:anotherParam"`, this shouldn't be the case anymore.